# How to get a Bootstrap tab to stay the same after submitting a form?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So first of all, this is not the same as refreshing the page, what I need is it to happen after submitting a form as well.

The form is handled in PHP.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <hr />
        <div class="tabbable tabs-left" id="myTab">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Manage categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Manage sections</a></li>
            <li><a href="#4" data-toggle="tab">Manage Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="#5" data-toggle="tab">Manage warnings</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <h2>Content</h2>
        <hr />
        <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="1"><?php require'include/home.php'; ?></div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="2"><?php require'include/categories.php'; ?></div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="3"><?php require'include/sections.php'; ?></div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="4"><?php require'include/users.php'; ?></div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="5"><?php require'include/warnings.php'; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**In categories.php is a form that uses the post method.**

The JQuery that I find that works after refreshing but not submitting a form is this:

```
<script>
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});

// store the currently selected tab in the hash value
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    $.cookie('activeTab', id);
});

    // on load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab
    var hash = $.cookie('activeTab');
    if (hash != null) {
        $('#myTab a[href="#' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not switch to a jQuery AJAX submit instead?

Comment: @Volomike Because I don't know how that would work and that would mean I have to learn something completely new, which I currently do not have the time for and I don't feel like doing so at the moment.

Comment: you already know jQuery. It's not much of a leap.

Comment: Tell you what. If you can simply the problem down to its bare necessities, and load it up on https://jsfiddle.net/ and link to it, I'll spend the time to show you how to do this much easier with jQuery and AJAX. You'll wonder why you didn't explore it sooner. Trying to code without jQuery AJAX is like trying to drive these days without automatic transmission -- it's so much easier, and everyone does it this way now, especially for the problem you describe.

Comment: @Volomike I fixed it, I was just being dumb and a PHP error stopped it from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change anything after submitting a form except for changing data in a particular place, you can use AJAX. Just create a onclick function on submit button without actually submitting the form, from that call the AJAX function, import the data you want and then insert it.

PS: AJAX is very easy, just check for a simple example and you can get it.
Here's an example

```
<script>
    function ajax(){
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var doc = document.getElementById("ajax_here");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function(e){
            if(hr.readyState==4 && hr.status==200){
                doc.innerHTML = hr.responseText;
            }
        }
        var url = "about.php";   // From the destination file which 
                                 // contains required data.
        hr.open("POST",url,true);
        hr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
        hr.send();
        doc.innerHTML = "processing...";
    }
 </script>
    <body>
    <p onclick="ajax()">Click here for something awesome</p>
```

Comment: I tried that once and I didn't understand it at all.

Comment: Can you be more specific, where you did not understand, because that's the easiest way

Comment: The PHP code I have puts something in a database, when I tried to do it with JQuery, that is calling a PHP file after submitting a form, it didn't work. On a side note, why use AJAX instead of JQuery?

Comment: I also handle my errors in my PHP code, which I want to keep this way.

Comment: Actually Jquery makes some ajax functions simpler. In your case I recommend using jquery's [post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) . It will post your form and with preventDefault() the page will not reload.